# Calculate column width

Tags: php, css, width

I'm currently working on a tiny cms to improve my php knowledge and now I'm at a point where I don't know how to continue.

I'd to be able to set a container to a percentage of the total avaiable width, like 1/3 (33%), 3/4 (75%) and so on but I also want to check for margins, paddings and borders.

Let's say the Container is 600 pixels wide, the content elements have a margin-right of 20px, no borders and no paddings. There are 2 elements: 75% and 25% wide which should have the pixel widths of 435px and 145px.

I just cannot come up with a correct formula.

/Edit:
Looks like it's tougher than I thought.
The "new" problem is that I want to enable every imaginable comination of those column widths.
The next step would be to add a clearing DIV if the next column wouldn't fit in the row to start a new row.

And to make it a little bit more fun:
I don't know the number of elements that will fit in a row when calculating the width. I also don't want to iterate through the result set just to determine how many items would still fit just to start all over after the break.

//I did it. Yay.
Here's the jsfiddle Version: http://jsfiddle.net/UNvyd/
I'll use a PHP Version but the concept will remain the same.

There are two things that I'm not quiet happy with:

- I need to count up every elements (`gi_elCount`)
- The value 0.8 is hardcoded because the smallest column is 1/5. If the current width of all row-elements is above 4/5 I'll need the clear div.

I hope that might help someone else in the future.

///Fix: http://jsfiddle.net/UNvyd/ this should now really work for every kind of combinations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution.
At first we need to find the width of the smalles column with the given denominator. That will be 1/2, 1/3 and so one. Therefor we need to subtract the amount of possible margins from the width (which is: *(denominator minus one) multiplied by margin*) and divide that by the denominator.

This will give us: `Width - Margin * (Denominator - 1)) / Denominator`.

Now we have the smalles column width. If we want to get the width for a bigger column, we have to multiply this amount by the Numerator.

`(Width - Margin * (Denominator - 1)) / Denominator) * Numerator`

The remaining problem is: if you have a 3/4 column it has to be the calculated width plus two times the margin. To achive this, we will add the *margin multiplied by the (numerator minus one)*

`(Numerator - 1) * Margin`

Resulting formula:

`((Width - Margin * (Denominator - 1)) / Denominator) * Numerator + ((Numerator - 1) * Margin)`

After calculating the width, we need to apply a clearing element after the current column if the total width of the current row exceeds 80% of the available width (since we allow a smalles column of 1/5) of a clearing element before the current col if the total width is above the available width.

You can find a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/UNvyd/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper" data-smallesColumn="5">
    <div class="column" data-width="1/2"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="1/2"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="1/3"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="1/3"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="1/3"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="1/4"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="1/4"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="2/4"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="1/4"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="1/5"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="1/5"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="1/5"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="1/5"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="1/5"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="1/2"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="1/4"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="1/4"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="1/3"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="2/3"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="3/4"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="1/4"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="2/5"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="3/5"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="2/5"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="1/5"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="2/5"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="1/2"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="1/3"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="1/4"></div>
    <div class="column" data-width="4/5"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width:423px;
    background-color:red;
}
.column {
    height:20px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:18px;
    background-color:yellow;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
    height:2px;
    background-color:green;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var gi_wrapperWidth = $('#wrapper').innerWidth();
    var gi_columnMargin = parseInt($('.column').css('margin-right'));
    var gi_maxWidth = (gi_wrapperWidth - 4 * gi_columnMargin) * 0.8 + gi_columnMargin;
    var gi_elCount = 0;
    var gi_widthCount = 0;

    $('.column').each(function(){
       gi_elCount++;
       var lo_that = $(this);

       //Get the intended width
       var ls_dataWidth = lo_that.data('width');

       //Split x/y into x and y
       var la_widthArray = ls_dataWidth.split('/');
       var li_numerator = la_widthArray[0];
       var li_denominator = la_widthArray[1];

       //Do some math!
       //((Width - Margin * (Denominator - 1)) / Denominator) * Numerator + ((Numerator - 1) * Margin)
       var li_elWidth = ((gi_wrapperWidth - gi_columnMargin * (li_denominator - 1)) / li_denominator) * li_numerator + ((li_numerator - 1) * gi_columnMargin);

        li_elWidth = parseFloat(li_elWidth.toFixed(2));

       //Set the width and show it inside the element
       lo_that.css('width', li_elWidth+'px').html(li_elWidth+'px');

       gi_widthCount += li_elWidth;
       if (Math.floor(gi_widthCount) > (gi_wrapperWidth - ((gi_elCount-1) * gi_columnMargin))) {
           gi_widthCount = li_elWidth;
           gi_elCount = 1;
           lo_that.before('<div class="clear"></div>');
       }

       else if (Math.floor(gi_widthCount) > gi_maxWidth) {
           lo_that.css('margin-right', '0px');
           gi_widthCount = 0;
           gi_elCount = 0;
           lo_that.after('<div class="clear"></div>');
       }

    });
});
```

The formula might need improvements but I'm quiet happy with the result so I'll stick with this.

I recommend not using this as a js but a php/server side solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Getting the right basis:**

> (Container width[600] - (margin-right[20] x (least common multiple[4] -1) )) / least common multiple[4] = Desired 25% width (**135**)

So for your 3/4 1/4 case: (600 - (20 x (4 - 1))) / 4 = **135**

For 2/3 1/3 case: (600 - (20 x (3 - 1))) / 3 = **186.66**

**Combining freely**

That is a mathematical problem, since you need to have the corect least common multiple to calculate the correct basis via the above formula

Example: 1/4 & 1/3: Least common multiple of 4 and 3: 12, 4/12 = 1/3 and 3/12 = 1/4. You still have 5/12 to split up.

Example 2: 1/3 and 2/5: Least common multiple of 5 and 3: 15, 5/15 = 1/3 6/15 = 2/5 You still have 4/15 to split up.

Comment: To be honest that won't work. Here's why:
Let's use the combination of a 2/3 (66%) and a 1/3 (33%) column. The result would be: 600 - (20 * 2) / 3 = 373.33px & 186.67px.

That might be ok but if I'd set three cols with 33% each I end up with this: 600 - (20 * 3) / 3 = 180px & 180px & 180px

So I've set 1/3 columns but depending on the other colums in that row, the size will differ. That's not that cool.

In fact the width of a 1/3 column should be: 186.67px
The 1/4 column should be 135px wide: (600 - 3*20) / 4 = 135 since I want the last column to have no right margin.

Comment: Thanks for your edit but the updated solution still isn't working. If you set 4 columns, each 25% wide, they should have a width of 135px and so should have the 1/4 column in the 3/4 & 1/4 case.

Comment: I changed my suggestion which should be the right solution for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but it seems you cannot turn that into a formular. What's with combinations like 1/3 & 1/4 or 1/3 & 2/5? I'd like to be able to use every combinations of thirds, quarters, fifths.

Comment: Unless you come up with something new, I think that should do it now.

Comment: Well I'd like to satisfy you but I - indeed - can still come up with something new. If you just have a 2/3 column, the result would be (600 - (20 x (3-1))) / 3 = 186.67 which I'd need to multiply by the numerator. - Works. But for the 1/4 & 1/3 combination it won't work: The smallest common multiple is 12 so the formula would be: (600 - (20 x (12 - 1))) / 12 = 31.67. That multiplied by 3 and 4 will result in the wrong widths.

Comment: Judging from your last edit to your question the simplest solution is: Add Elemnts to container (ie line) until margin for the last allready present element + new column width <= total width if it is greater add a "clearing div" and start a new line.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done with CSS alone. You can Use jQuery to do it. Assuming you have a 20px right margin on each element, we subtract that margin and calculate 25% and 75% width for each element.

```
var cw = $('#container').width();
$('#element1').css({'width':parseInt((cw * 0.25)-20)+"px"});
$('#element2').css({'width':parseInt((cw * 0.75)-20)+"px"});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/uV62M/

Comment: Thanks for your reply but calculating the width of the content client side is not an option.